# Limit inferior and indicator function

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on a measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$. Define the sets $A :=\{x \in \Omega \mid \liminf_{n \rightarrow +\infty} f_n(x) > \alpha\}$ and $B:=\liminf_{n \rightarrow + \infty} \{x \in \Omega \mid f_n(x) > \alpha\}$. Is $A \subset B$ or $B \subset A$ or $A=B$ or they are disjoint sets? Can we say $\mathcal{X}_A(x)=\mathcal{X}_B(x)$ (where $\mathcal{X}_A(\cdot)$ denotes the characteristic function of the set $A$)?

**My approach:**
I suspect that $A \subset \cap_n \cap_{m \geqslant n}\{x \in \Omega \mid f_m(x) > \alpha\}$. If this is true then it will be easy to show that $A \subset B$, but I am stuck mid-way. Any help/clue will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The inclusion that you want to show does not hold in general. Take e.g. $f_1(x)=0$ for all $x$ and $f_m(x)=1$ for all $x$. If $\alpha=1/2$ then $A=\Omega$ and $\bigcap_n\bigcap_{m\geq n}\{x\in\Omega\mid f_m(x)>\alpha\}\subseteq\{x\in\Omega\mid f_1(x)>\alpha\}=\emptyset$. However, if $x\in A$ you can deduce that there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f_m(x)>\alpha$ for all $m\geq n$. Hence, $x\in B$, and this proves the inclusion $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: @jakobdt Thanks for the reply. Can you please elaborate a little bit, especially your second argument after the counter-example?

Comment: If $x\in A$ then $\liminf_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)>\alpha$. Hence, there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\inf_{m\geq n}f_m(x)>\alpha$. So for any $m\geq n$ you have $f_m(x)>\alpha$. That is, $x\in\bigcap_{m\geq n}\{x\in\Omega\mid f_m(x)>\alpha\}\subseteq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\{x\in\Omega\mid f_n(x)>\alpha\}$.

Comment: @jakobdt Sure got it. Thanks a lot.